# Why do the <select> options jump to a different option when I hover over it?

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

So I have an interesting issue.  I have a `<select>` menu, and it is all working as I would like with one exception.  When I hover over any of the `<options>`, the highlighted option skip from the option I am hovering over, to the top value (and it seems to make no difference whether it is marked as 'selected,' or not).  When I click it selects the correct option, not the highlighted one.  It works correctly in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Can anyone explain to me why it behaves like this, and what I might do.

Thanks!

```
<select name="grade" id="grade" value="" >
   <option value="4" selected >A</option>
   <option value="3.7" >A-</option>
   <option value="3.4" >B+</option>
   <option value="3" >B</option>
   <option value="2.7" >B-</option>
   <option value="2.4" >C+</option>
   <option value="2" >C</option>
   <option value="1.7" >C-</option>
   <option value="1" >D</option>
   <option value="0" >E</option>
</select>
```

Here is the only time I use this in my JavaScript.  And as I said, it is only not functioning in google-chrome.

```
var in_gpa = Number($('#grade').val());
```

Comment: @Eman : You havent posted whole code..can you demonstarte the same here http://jsfiddle.net/4Ct7W/

Comment: @user1042031 I'm not sure what code you after here.  As far as I can tell its pretty typical html code set up in php.

Comment: It also seems to be a problem only in chrome.

Comment: there **should** be some javascript code, and I think the main problem is there

Comment: are there any functions that are being called when mouseover event has occurred?

Comment: @Eman why you are self closing the option tags?

Comment: @haynar I've tried it both ways with no change in result.

Comment: @V413HAV great observation, the incorrect HTML could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly same problem in Chrome Only!

Problem: Chrome extention:FastestChrome - Browse Faster 6.9.7

Answer (score 1):

You are self closing the select and option tag, try this and see, moreover you can't set a value for `<select>` tag.

```
<select name="grade" id="grade">
   <option value="4" selected>A</option>
   <option value="3.7">A-</option>
   <option value="3.4">B+</option>
   <option value="3">B</option>
   <option value="2.7">B-</option>
   <option value="2.4">C+</option>
   <option value="2">C</option>
   <option value="1.7">C-</option>
   <option value="1">D</option>
   <option value="0">E</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling AdBlock when installed. This caused jumping options in dropdowns for me.